# Excel Automation 'FitToPagesWide' not supported by automation object

Tags: excel, delphi, ole

I'm trying to export an Excel sheet to PDF and I'd like the sheet to fit within the width of the page.  In doing some research, it seems that I should use FitToPagesWide, however, I'm unable to find Delphi examples.. Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.ExcelToPDF(const AFilename: string);
Const
  XlTypePDF = 0;
  xlQualityStandard = 0;
  IncludeDocProperties = true;
  IgnorePrintAreas = false;
  LandscapeMode = 2;
var
  P: OleVariant;
begin
  P:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    P.WorkBooks.Open(AFilename, 3);
    p.ActiveSheet.Pagesetup.Orientation := LandscapeMode;   orientation
    p.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide := 1;   // <-- not supported by automation object
    p.ActiveWorkbook.exportAsFixedFormat(xlTypePDF,
                                         AFilename,
                                         xlQualityStandard,
                                         IncludeDocProperties,
                                         IgnorePrintAreas );
  finally
    p.Quit;
  end;
```

Comment: Did you try "true"?

Comment: Take out the `:`, it should just be `...FirtToPagesWide = 1`

Comment: @BruceWayne: that would make Delphi read the `FitToPagesWide` property value and then compare it to 1 (turning the statement into a boolean expression, which is not legal in this context). It would not assign 1 to the `FitToPagesWide` property, which is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @JohnEasley: what version of Excel do you have installed? `FitToPagesWide` is only available in Excel 2010 and later.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have 2013

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I tried true and 'true' and get error "unable to set the FitToPagesWide property of the PageSetup class"..so at least its aware of the method in this case..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I got it working.  It seems I have to set Zoom := false, FitToPagesTall := 1 before setting FitToPagesWide.. strange..

Comment: @JohnEasley: well, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194365.aspx) does say you have to disable `Zoom` for `FitToPages...` to have an effect, but it doesn't say you have to set `FitToPagesTall` first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I read the docs as "if zoom is true, then FitToPagesWide is ignored", it doesn't say that it should explicitly be set to false (which I assumed Zoom default is false, my bad).  If you put an answer together with details I will accept it.. I won't accept my own answer..

Comment: I'd think the default for "Zoom" would be 100. Anyway, this is not the first time working out some office automation involves trial and error...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I agree, but the 'not supported' message threw me off.. made me think I had a late binding issue.. thanks for you help, the 'true' test helped me figure it out as it threw a different message, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that setting the Zoom and FitToPagesTall properties before setting FitToPagesWide works.

```
p.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom := false;
P.Activesheet.Pagesetup.FitToPagesTall := 1;
p.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide := 1;
```